# Not able to replicate large values with apache geode wan replication

Tags: caching, redis, gemfire, geode

I am trying to replicate a very large value using apache geode. What I am basically doing is to use setbit function of redis. As I keep increasing the offset for setbit function, the geode server crashes. I am using the redis adaptor of geode as client.

```
import redis.clients.jedis.*;
import redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisException;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisException;

public class Test {

    //address of your redis server
    private static final String redisHost = "10.0.0.10";
    private static final Integer redisPort = 11211;

    //remember to increase sensder queue size 
    public void addSets() {
        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        poolConfig.setMaxIdle(50);
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(1000);
        poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
        JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(poolConfig,redisHost, redisPort,10000000);
        Jedis jedis= null;
        String key = "shivd";
        long [] bits = {1464236631,12373513,1488983657,1329373495,147236649,1623846793,1194510359,282099785,1758709929,1059647223,416962921,1893573065,924784087,551826057,2028436201}; 

        //get a jedis connection jedis connection pool
        try {
            jedis = pool.getResource();
            Pipeline pipeline = jedis.pipelined();

            for (long b : bits) {

                pipeline.setbit(key, b, true);
            }
            pipeline.multi();
            pipeline.exec();

        } finally {
            if (jedis != null) {
                jedis.close();
            }
        }
        pool.destroy();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test main = new Test();
        main.addSets();
        //main.cal();
        //main.addHash();
    }
}
```

If I decrease the offset to some limit, it works. 
Here is the log of both the cache servers using redis adaptor:

dc1.log(10.0.0.10) - where I am inserting the key

[dc1.log](https://github.com/codophobia/redis/blob/master/redis.log)

dc2.log(where replication happens)

[dc2.log](https://github.com/codophobia/redis/blob/master/redis1.log)

Answer (score 0):

Your Geode server is running out of memory. The last value in your is `2028436201`, which would need about 253MB to store in memory.

You can give more memory to the Geode server with something like:

```
gfsh>start server --name=serv1 --max-heap=2G
```

If your offsets are that big, you can also try to base your bitset at the lowest offset. (i.e. subtract the lowest offset from each offset before storing, and then maintain the lowest offset externally).